# Why do I have 502 error with my GitLab server on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab

I installed GitLab using [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial

I got 502 error

[image]

I open 8081 port,and edit my gitlab.rb file properly

```
unicorn[‘port’] = 8081
```

How to fix this?
Why is Nginx showing Bad Gateway?

My netstat output

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11833/unicorn maste 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3230/puma 3.12.0 (t 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1031/ruby           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1704/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11833/unicorn master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server is giving a 502 Gateway surely there is a configuration issue. Maybe a Gitlab daemon/Port problem

Try reconfiguring the gitlab

**gitlab-ctl reconfigure**

Still facing problem **try changing the port number then reconfigure.**

Use this link for more https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/28579

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/28579

Comment: The above lilnk will be helpfull